# Eventhub Connection Issue from Docker as well in kubernetes

Tags: c#, docker, azure-eventhub, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a code, which uses the Confluent Kafka library, written in C#.
I Am able to connect to the Azure event hub from my local system properly.
However, when I put the same in the container. I get the following error.

```
3|1656401522.469|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#consumer-1: sasl_ssl://xyz.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap: Disconnected (after 148ms in state UP)
%6|1656401522.626|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://xyz.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://xyz.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap: Disconnected (after 124ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)


%3|1656399913.942|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://xyz.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1656399922.791|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://xyz.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[9]
      BackgroundService failed
      Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Broker: Topic authorization failed
```

Any suggestions here ? Anyone ?

New Error

```
Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 0ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

Any my configuration

```
                    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
                    BootstrapServers = _configuration["KAFKA_SERVER"],
                    GroupId = consumerGroup,
                    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
                    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
                    SaslUsername = "$ConnectionString",
                    SaslPassword = _configuration["EVENTHUB_CONNSTR"],
                    SslCaLocation = _configuration["EVENTHUB_CA_CERT_LOCATION"]
```

Comment: How are you authenticating yourself to kafka? It looks like this authorization method is not passed to the container as expected.

Comment: @YaronIdan You mean the settings/configuration you are asking for ? Something like below ones   EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
BootstrapServers = brokerList,
GroupId = consumerGroup,
AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
SaslUsername = "$ConnectionString",
SaslPassword = connStr,
SslCaLocation = caCertLocation

Comment: My point was that some of the configurations you've mentioned in your comments are not passed as expected to the container. It might be the value of the `$ConnectionString` env var, or the contents of the `caCertLocation` path. Look into these details since they are most probably the root cause of the error you've met.

Comment: @YaronIdan Thanks, i did check those, for caCert i used to get a error, when the path was incorrect, I had fixed that earlier. Regarding the ConnectionString, its not the env variable. I read in document that to connect to EventHub from confluentKafka, we need to pass that as a string. That $ConnectionString itself is a value. Ref : https://notetoself.tech/2018/06/03/acessing-event-hubs-with-confluent-kafka-library/

Comment: @YaronIdan Any further thoughts ?

Comment: Have you gone over all of the authorization parameters and made sure they are passed correctly to the container?

Comment: Yes, i did check again. Not getting what am missing.

Comment: Today am getting a new error  Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 0ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)

Comment: @YaronIdan More updates in my description

Comment: Am getting closer, it looks like AKS is not able to connect to Azure Eventhub, I have configured eventhub to work for specific whitelisted IPs. So, question is where would i get the IP of kubernetes (AKS) ? @YaronIdan

Comment: The IP should be the same as the loadbalancer used by your ingress controller, unless you are using a NAT gateway - in which case it would be its IP.